# shc compilation from bash to binary file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and I converted bash script to binary file. Example:

```
shc -v -T -r -f test.sh
```

File test.sh has code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test"
```

After compilation I got 2 files (test.sh.x and test.sh.x.c).
When I trying execute test.sh.x I got nothing.

I try to trace it (strace ./test.sh.x) but strace show me infinite output.

```
stat("/home/master/Desktop", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/master/Desktop", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/master/Desktop/BOX", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/master", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 22371
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26258, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7f2ec76ba000
close(3)                                = 0
getppid()                               = 22369
brk(0x12ff000)                          = 0x12ff000
brk(0x1300000)                          = 0x1300000
brk(0x1301000)                          = 0x1301000
getpgrp()                               = 22369
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7fff6581f8ec)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x44cf60, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7fff6581f8cc)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=31314, rlim_max=31314}) = 0
brk(0x1302000)                          = 0x1302000
brk(0x1303000)                          = 0x1303000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
getpeername(0, 0x7fff6581fa10, 0x7fff6581fa0c) = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
brk(0x1304000)                          = 0x1304000
brk(0x1305000)                          = 0x1305000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, {0x44cf60, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f2ec6ce07f0}, 8) = 0
execve("/home/master/Desktop/BOX/test.sh.x", ["./test.sh.x"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x562df4879000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2827d84000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=135904, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 135904, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2827d62000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\5\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1856752, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3959200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f282779b000
mprotect(0x7f2827959000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2827b58000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7f2827b58000
mmap(0x7f2827b5e000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2827b5e000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2827d60000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2827d60700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2827b58000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x562df34f2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2827d87000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f2827d62000, 135904)          = 0
getpid()                                = 22371
brk(NULL)                               = 0x562df4879000
brk(0x562df489a000)                     = 0x562df489a000
execve("/bin/bash", ["./test.sh.x", "-c", "exec './test.sh.x' \"$@\"", "./test.sh.x"], [/* 72 vars */]strace: Process 22371 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Could somebody tell me how fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: The `strace` output doesn't match your problem description. Meaning you start `./install.sh.x`, not `./test.sh.x`. We can only guess why that script doesn't work. The simple `test.sh.x` works as expected for me. Btw, use `strace -f` to follow child processes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using test.sh for example. My main script has name install.sh.

Comment: No need to say sorry, but you need to put all facts into the question which are required to solve the problem. In the current form it is just not reproducible.

Comment: I'm using shc it from main box. Maybe someone have the same problem and know how it solving. That's I'm asking about. Or maybe try to install shc from source files or previous versions?

Comment: Please run `strace -f ./test.sh.x` instead of `strace ./test.sh.x`

Comment: Used. Files which opening during execution (all off there are exist):

open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3

Comment: The `-f` wasn't necessary, my bad. (But it doesn't hurt). Can't reproduce that. Works for me.

Comment: Maybe a dump of test.sh.x.c would be relevant ?

Comment: I'm tried to compile test.sh.x.c by gcc but the problem still exist. It doesn't matter.